# Entity Framework Core - Sorting on Calculated Field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a model similar to this:

```
Public class Item {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
  public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
  public int? TotalTime
  {
    get
    {
      return Convert.ToInt32(EndTime.Value - StartTime.Value).TotalMinutes);
    }
  }
  etc...
```

Then I get a list of Items:

```
IQueryable<Items> items = itemsContext.Items.Where(e => e.Id > 0);
```

I do some calculations, run some other code, then at the end I want to return the list of Items ordered by Name ASC and TotalTime DESC. This is what I tried:

```
items = items.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ThenByDescending(e => e.TotalTime);
```

But I get an error: *"The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()."*

I also tried this, but get the same error:

```
items = items.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ThenByDescending(e => e.TotalTime ?? 0);
```

How can I sort my data set by TotalTime?

Comment: Don't try that. TotalTime property cannot be calculated one the server, because EF do not see expression tree, just property call. Which code is under property getter is  hidden. So EF cannot translate this expression,

Comment: btw, avoid `Convert.ToInt32` because it doesn't give you control over error-handling. You can safely cast `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` directly to `Int32`.

Comment: For such in-record calculations it's always the best option to add a computed column to the database and map it to your EF model as computed.

Answer (score 2):

- As `TotalTime` is not part of your database, so you need to annotate it with `[NotMapped]`.
- Then you need to first **load** the items and *then* sort by them.
- However if you want to perform paging or sorting within your database server then you need to use `EndTime` and `StartTime` directly in your query.

#### Approach 1: Loading first, then sorting in application code:

```
List<Items> loadedItems = await itemsContext.Items
    .Where( e => e.Id > 123 )
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false); // `ConfigureAwait(false)` MAY be optional, depending on your application.

List<Items> sortedItems = loadedItems
    .OrderBy(e => e.Name)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.TotalTime)
    .ToList(); // <-- Note this is NOT `ToListAsync` because the items are already loaded into memory.
```

#### Approach 2: Sorting in SQL:

```
List<Items> loadedSortedItems = await itemsContext.Items
    .Where( e => e.Id > 123 )
    .OrderBy( e => e.Name )
    .ThenByDescending( e => e.EndTime - e.StartTime )
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

#### Changes to your class

I'd modify your class to be something like this:

```
public class Item {
  public int       Id        { get; set; }
  public string    Name      { get; set; }
  public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
  public DateTime? EndTime   { get; set; }
  
  [NotMapped]
  public int? TotalTimeMinutes
  {
    get
    {
        if( this.EndTime == null || this.StartTime == null ) return null;

        TimeSpan diff = this.EndTime.Value - this.StartTime.Value;
        return (Int32)Math.Round( diff.TotalMinutes );
    }
  }
```

- The `NotMapped` attribute makes it clear to Entity Framework that it should ignore the property.
- Note how the property includes the unit name ("Minutes") otherwise it's non-obvious if the property is milliseconds, seconds, minutes, etc.
- Also note how the property checks if `StartTime` and `EndTime` are null and returns `null` in that case. Your code did not, which means your program will crash if ther are `NULL` values in the database or if any `Item` object instances are not fully initialized.
- If `StartTime` and `EndTime` values *cannot* be `NULL` then you need to add `NOT NULL` to your database and update your EF entity classes so the properties are `DateTime` and not `DateTime?`.

Comment: OK. Thanks. [NotMapped] isn't necessary if you don't have both, a getter and a setter Also, thanks for the notes on the time calculation. I meant to write a simple example that is easy to follow and represents a more complex situation. I resolved my issue by calling ToList() first before attempting to sort.

Comment: second approach is not correct approach

Comment: @HamedHajiloo Please explain why you feel it’s incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You should translate the SQL DateDiff method to EF Core.
for this approach, you can use from below method.

```
EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(c.StartDate, c.EndDate ?? DateTime.Now)
```